# Linq join with newest record of second table

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have two related tables `Ticket` and `Status`.

Every ticket can be multiple status. (Open, assigned, closed). But I want all tickets but only one status (newest date) to show.

I could handle with this query on t-sql;

```
SELECT d.ticketID, statusName, c.statusDate, c.assignedTo,c.statusID
FROM Ticket d LEFT JOIN Status c ON c.ticketID = d.ticketID
WHERE  c.statusID = (
    SELECT MAX(statusID)
    FROM Status c2
    WHERE c2.ticketID = d.ticketID)
```

This is my Linq :

```
var result = from t in db.Ticket
             join s in db.Status.OrderByDescending(x=>x.statusDate).Take(1) 
             on t.ticketID equals s.ticketID join c in db.Customer 
             on t.customerID equals c.customerID
```

But this only returning one row.

Comment: _"But this only returning one row."_... What does `Take(1)` do?

Comment: :) You're right, but I am trying to take the status that newest date. One status for each ticket. But its returning only one ticket.

Comment: Your SQL is taking the MAX(statusID) not the date. Try : OrderByDescending(x=>x.statusID).Take(1)..  I would remove the Take(1) for debugging and make sure everything else is working.

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem with linqer application via converting my Tsql query to linq

```
from s in db.Status
                     where s.statusID ==
                         (from c2 in db.Status where
                               c2.ticketID == s.Ticket.ticketID &&
                               c2.statusName == "New" ||
                               c2.statusName == "Assigned"
                          select new
                          {
                              c2.statusID
                          }).Max(p => p.statusID)
```

Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your original linq logic to:

```
var result = from t in db.Ticket
join s in db.Status on t.ticketID equals s.ticketID into sGroup
from s in sGroup.OrderByDescending(x=>x.statusDate).Take(1)
join c in db.Customer 
on t.customerID equals c.customerID
```